# Computing eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given the following matrix
$$\left(  \begin{matrix} 0 &1&0\\0&0&1\\1&-1&0 \end{matrix}  \right).$$
Now I computed the characteristic polynomial of $A$ to be $p_A(\lambda) = \lambda^3+\lambda-1.$ This means that all eigenvalues are positive and thus the system $\dot{x} = Ax+Bu$ is unstable. Now I wonder if there is any way someone can find the exact eigenvalues, I tried to factorize the characteristic polynomial endlessly but couldn't get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ayman Hourieh, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial.  A cubic can be solved using radicals, but the result is rather messy:
$$
\frac16\,\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}-2\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{108+12\,
\sqrt {93}}}}$$ $$-\frac{1}{12}\,\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3
]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}}}+\frac{i\sqrt {3}}{2} \left( \frac16\,\sqrt [3]{108+12\,
\sqrt {93}}+2\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}}} \right) $$ $$-\frac{1}{
12}\,\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {
93}}}}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2} \left( \frac16\,\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}+2\,{
\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{108+12\,\sqrt {93}}}} \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

If you check again, you should find that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is in fact $\lambda^3+\lambda+1.$ It isn't nicely factorable (though [Cardano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_formula#Cardano.27s_method) may be used to do so), but has one negative root and two complex conjugate imaginary roots.

Comment: ah I cant believe I got that wrong, thanks for spotting that!

Comment: You're welcome!